# Can following-sibling get many attributes?

Tags: python, xpath

I have a structure like this.

```html
 <li class="Title">This</li>
 <li><a href="">AAA</a></li>
 <li><a href="">BBB</a></li>
 <li><a href="">CCC</a></li>
 <li class="Title">That</li>
 <li><a href="">DDD</a></li>
 <li><a href="">EEE</a></li>
```

And this is My xpath :

```
 sites = sel.xpath("//li[@class='Title']")
 for i,site in enumerate(sites):
      print i
      state = site.xpath("./text()")
      city = site.xpath("./following-sibling::li/a/text()")
```

And the result is

```
 0
 This 
 AAA
 1
 That 
 DDD
```

But I want also want to select all siblings not only one

How can I do to select all sibling `li` under the `<li class="Title">`

like :

```
This 
AAA
This 
BBB
This 
CCC

That 
DDD
That 
EEE
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I  learned a lot.

Comment: not a problem and glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative (to check only siblings after  element, you can loop through the siblings and break through if another  element is reached.
Something like this:

```
import lxml

# I wrap your sample with an empty div
s = '''<div><li class="Title">This</li>
     <li><a href="">AAA</a></li>
     <li><a href="">BBB</a></li>
     <li><a href="">CCC</a></li>
 <li class="Title">That</li>
     <li><a href="">DDD</a></li>
     <li><a href="">EEE</a></li></div>'''

tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(s)
# search for all <li> with "Title" element
for node in tree.xpath('.//li[@class="Title"]'):
    print '\n'
    # loop in <li class="Title"> to find for any siblings with <a> element
    for sub in node.xpath('.//following-sibling::li'):
        # break out the loop if another <li class="Title"> is found
        # you can implement other logic to break out as well 
        if sub.get('class') == 'Title':
            break
        print node.text
        print ''.join(sub.xpath('./a/text()'))
```

Results:

```
This
AAA
This
BBB
This
CCC

That
DDD
That
EEE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import lxml.etree as etree

string = '''
<root>
  <li class="Title">This</li>
  <li><a href="">AAA</a></li>
  <li><a href="">BBB</a></li>
  <li><a href="">CCC</a></li>
  <li class="Title">That</li>
  <li><a href="">DDD</a></li>
  <li><a href="">EEE</a></li>
</root>
'''

st = ", "

tree = etree.fromstring(string)

for i, node in enumerate(tree.xpath('//li[@class="Title"] | //li/a')):
    seq = (str(i), node.text, node.attrib.keys()[0])
    print st.join(seq)
```

#### OUTPUT :

```
0, This, class
1, AAA, href
2, BBB, href
3, CCC, href
4, That, class
5, DDD, href
6, EEE, href
```

#### NOTE :

Now, you have enough to start the type of **li** to branch what you want, but take care, there's no **li** child elements despite of the meaning of your original indentation in your POST.

Comment: OK, that's nice. Now what? I don't see how this solves OP's question.

Comment: Have you tested ? This make the output as `This
AAA
BBB
CCC
That
DDD
EEE`. This is the expected output of the OP. You have re-indented the OP xml post where there's no childs **li** elements, it was better non indented.

Comment: Oh, now I see why you edited it. You're right, no children. You might want to point that out in your answer, through. Good catch.